# Request & Response schema of django-rest-swagger for documenting the API in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I want to document my API using swagger generator tool [django-rest-swagger](http://marcgibbons.github.io/django-rest-swagger/) in DRF

right now I am writing views by inheriting `rest_framework.views.APIView`

I don't want to write views using viewsets nor serializer.

Here is the view code sample

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class SomeView(APIView):
  '''
  get:
    some description
  post:
    some other description
 '''
 def get(self, request, format=None):
    a = self.request.query_params.get('a',None)
    b = self.request.query_params.get('b',None)
    c = self.request.query_params.get('c',None)
    return Response({},status='200')

 def post(self, request, format=None):
    a = self.request.data.get('a',None)
    b = self.request.data.get('b',None)
    c = self.request.data.get('c',None)
    return Response({},status='201')
```

Right now I am able to add description for each endpoint. 
[image: description for each api endpoint in swagger ui]

and I want to add request & response schema like below [image: model schema for each endpoint in swagger]

and I am wondering, how to achieve this without using serializers & viewsets.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: python 3.5 @vishes_shell

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of django-rest-swagger YAML docstrings (as in your example) have been deprecated I believe. Accordingly, I think you would need to manually define your schema. The docs include an example of how to do this on the view level:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#manualschema

Comment: how do i differentiate if i have more than one method in one class. i mean how to write manual schema if have get,post,delete methods in one class ??

Comment: Hmmm good question. I guess you could fully define the schema by hand as per this example: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#internal-schema-representation. However, at that point you may as well just be writing your swagger by hand since you get no benefits of auto-generation.

Answer (score 1):

I know that i'm not answering directly to your question, but i would like to suggest you to try an awesome package that is customizable in every direction: [`drf-yasg`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg). You are not obligated to use generic rest_framework stuff nor serializers.

You can jump directly to [Custom schema generation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html)